# My scripts is erroring out as avikanch1 Venkat@4444 send: spawn id exp5 not open while executing "send "Venkat@4444\r""

Tags: linux

```
#!/bin/bash
user=`cat userdetails | cut -d "," -f1`
user_pass=`cat userdetails | cut -d "," -f2`
echo $user
echo $user_pass

/usr/bin/expect > file.tmp << EOF
        spawn passwd $user
        expect "New UNIX password:"
        send "$user_pass\r"
        expect "Retype new UNIX password:"
        send "$user_pass\r"
        expect "*#*"
EOF
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Could you explain your question in a details except of console output?

Comment: i am passing my details in from another file and trying to reset the password for new user

Comment: My expectations if suppose my user is avikanch1 and password is ghty@3333 it should reset the password for the user with the new one. user is already existed but password is not known to me since its a new user created by me